# Laravel / Valet installation (php 7.2, valet version 2, laravel version 5.6)

Tags: php, macos, laravel, laravel-valet

I followed the laravel.com 5.6 valet [installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#installation)

1. Install or update Homebrew to the latest version using brew update.
2. Install PHP 7.2 using Homebrew via brew install homebrew/php/php72.

3.Install Valet with Composer via composer global require laravel/valet. Make sure the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory is in your system's "PATH".

4. Run the valet install command. This will configure and install Valet and DnsMasq, and register Valet's daemon to launch when your system starts.

The only difference is that when I went through this, on #2 I just did brew install php72, and created a symbolic link.

I go into Sites, and create a folder called iasig-admire (i tried serving it, I'm able to see the site)

`cd Sites`

then do

`valet park`

I go to 127.0.0.1 and it says "It works!"

I go to iasig-admire.test and it says

[image]

It's not because of dnsmasq. dnsmasq is running.

[image]

I updated the .test,  url to .app (your-site.app instead of your-site.test):

[image]

Different browser and url is .app for testing:

[image]

Pinging fails also:

[image]

I know there are tons of these valet issues but I've checked through them and tried running through what I've found, and gotten no results. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found out that it was because I had an invalid path in valet. To figure this out, I typed

`valet path`

[image]

The .valet/Sites path was causing issues, when I went into the .valet directory and did

`valet forget`

The path that I'm trying to get to is now working, valet is now working correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This somehow solves my problem. After removing the path I relink all my projects then I restart my machine.

Comment: Glad it was helpful to you @AlyssaReyes